# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'on')

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

```
          editorRef.current.on('change',(instance,changes) => {
              console.log('changes',changes);

              const {origin} =changes;
              const code =instance.getValue();
                // console.log(code);
              if(origin !== 'setValue' ){
                socketRef.current.emit(ACTIONS.CODE_CHANGE,{
                  roomId,
                  code,
                });
              }
            });
socketRef.current.on(ACTIONS.CODE_CHANGE,( {code} )=>{
              if(code !== null){
                editorRef.current.setValue(code);
              }
            })
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MparB.jpg)

using socket.io to connect to server for an editor application using react